# Saving Json data to Sqlite Python

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I am trying to save my Json data that I have pulled from a URL, but I am struggling to save it in an SQLite database.

Json:

{"Address":"ff00000a70d57128","Celsius":26.8125,"Fahrenheit":80.2625}

I have looked around and gained from inspiration from:

[saving json data into sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34966712/saving-json-data-into-sqlite)
[Convert JSON to SQLite in Python - How to map json keys to database columns properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811783/convert-json-to-sqlite-in-python-how-to-map-json-keys-to-database-columns-prop)

```py
import threading
import json
import urllib.request
import sqlite3

def tempRequest():
    # download raw json object
    url = "http://10.0.0.111:8080/getdevice?device=type28_1"
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()

    # parse json object
    obj = json.loads(data)
    print(obj)

tempRequest()

conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_table():
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data(Celcius TEXT)")

def data_entry():
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO data (Celcius) ''VALUES (:Celcius)

    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    conn.close()

create_table()
data_entry()
```

What i get when i am running this is:

TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not ellipsis

I have tried to change:

```py
obj = json.loads(data)
```

to

```py
obj = json.loads(str(data))
```

But i think that the issue is on how i handle the DB part, any advice would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: When you debug python script, `pdb` is your friend. Place `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` anywhere you want to stop, then run the script. The pdb interpreter came up, and you can inspect variable such as `data` just like python interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a proof of concept I wrote a short while back to download JSON stock data and store it in row format in SQLite.

Different data, same concept. Hope it helps

```
import json
import urllib.request
import sqlite3
from os import path

stocks = ['AAPL', "MSFT"]

connection = sqlite3.connect("C:\\Projects\\AIFX\\Spikes\\Data\\Stocks.db")
cursor = connection.cursor()

for stock in stocks:

    url = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3/historical-price-full/" + stock
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode()

    obj = json.loads(data)

    for child in obj['historical']:
        print(child)

        cursor.execute("Insert into StockPrices values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
                       (child['date'], child['close'], child['high'], child['low'], 
                       child['open'], child['volume'], stock))
        connection.commit()
```

The table definition for storing the data in SQLite is

```
CREATE TABLE "StockPrices" (
    "date"  TEXT,
    "close" INTEGER,
    "high"  INTEGER,
    "low"   INTEGER,
    "open"  INTEGER,
    "volume"    INTEGER,
    "symbol"    TEXT
);
```

The shape of the JSON is

```
{
  "symbol" : "AAPL",
  "historical" : [ {
    "date" : "2015-04-22",
    "open" : 126.99,
    "high" : 128.87,
    "low" : 126.32,
    "close" : 128.62,
    "adjClose" : 119.0,
    "volume" : 3.76545E7,
    "unadjustedVolume" : 3.76545E7,
    "change" : 1.63,
    "changePercent" : 1.284,
    "vwap" : 127.93667,
    "label" : "April 22, 15",
    "changeOverTime" : 0.01284
  }, {
    "date" : "2015-04-23",
    "open" : 128.3,
    "high" : 130.42,
    "low" : 128.14,
    "close" : 129.67,
    "adjClose" : 119.97,
    "volume" : 4.57709E7,
    "unadjustedVolume" : 4.57709E7,
    "change" : 1.37,
    "changePercent" : 1.068,
    "vwap" : 129.41,
    "label" : "April 23, 15",
    "changeOverTime" : 0.01068
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql()` method which can yahoo finance stock data to DB directly: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html